# How do I add a reset function?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How would I add a reset function to the IBOutlet, currently when the button is clicked then the timer will start and when the same button is clicked again it will stop, but when it is clicked a third time it will start again, but I want it to reset.

```
 @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
     if !timer.valid{

    let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        stoptimer.text = String(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)
     }
     else{
        timer.invalidate()


        }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not save a button state in a global variable, so you can do what you want?

Here is a quick example: (you can chance the title of the button here too)

```
var buttonState:Int = 0;

// func for buttonpress

@IBAction func startButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) { 

    switch(buttonState) {
       case 0:
          // button first pressed, run code

          // set state to 1:
          buttonState = 1;
       break;

       case 1:
          // button second tap, run code

          // set state to 2:
          buttonState = 2;
       break;

       case 2:
          // button third tap, run code

          // reset state to 0:
          buttonState = 0;
       break;

 ....
```

Comment: Thats of course also possible. It should just give the User a way how to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set one bool for it as shown in below code:

```
var stopTime = false

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

    if !timer.valid && !stopTime{

        let aSelector : Selector = "updateTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        var startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        stoptimer.text = String(arc4random_uniform(4)+1)

    }else if stopTime{

        //reset you timer here
        //reset your bool as per your need.
        println("Reset")

    } else {

        stopTime = true
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

When you click on start button when your timer is running it will enter into else and set your `stopTime` bool to `true` so that next time when you press start button it will not enter into that if condition because `stopTime` is `true` this time.

Comment: Are you sure it will reset it because it looks like it just stops the timer, I want the timer to stop and then the next click it will reset.

Answer (score 0):

Or without boolean

In your class, declare your timer as optional

```
var timer: NSTimer?
```

In your @IBAction function:

```
if timer != nil {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
} else {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Do everything you want with your timers
}
```